How can I solidify this awkward geometry?
I have a realistic head scan that I want to turn into a doll head to 3D print, by giving it thickness with the solidify modifier. However, because of awkward geometry around the eyes, mouth and ears, the solidify modifier is producing some strange results and spikes that stick out of the head, as pictured. Checking 'even thickness' adds even more huge spikes. I am relatively new to Blender - how can I fix this?
Thank you
This is the head on its own:

This is the head with the overlapping protrusions produced by the solidify modifier:


Hello, I don't think that you can avoid that, faces will intersect because you have a lot of details, I guess you need to correct these areas manually

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

solidify modifier "just" extrudes faces along normals. If you think about that, it should be clear why they intersect. And as moonboots said -> you have to repair that manually (or use a complicated geometry nodes setup which i doubt is worth the effort)

Thanks, I was in denial that I would have to do much manually lol, but that makes a lot of sense
